# Incorrect mime type for CSV returned by file -i

Tags: debian, mime

On debian the `file -i` command is returning incorrect information for CSV files, when I run it the mime type is returned as below.

`$ file -i courses.csv
courses.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

I've looked in /etc/mime.types and the mime type is declared correctly in there so I can't work out what would be causing this.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect the file utility is working as designed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?